# Installing VS Code extensions in one go

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have installed multiple extensions for VS code. Now I want to install VS code in another system. Is there any way by which I can install these extension in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own "Extension Pack" with the extensions you need.

Please look at this python extension pack as an example

https://github.com/DonJayamanne/python-extension-pack